# How to use Python 3.4's enums without significant slowdown?

Tags: python, performance, enums, python-3.4

I was writing a tic-tac-toe game and using an Enum to represent the three outcomes -- `lose`, `draw`, and `win`. I thought it would be better style than using the strings `("lose", "win", "draw")` to indicate these values. But using enums gave me a significant performance hit.

Here's a minimal example, where I simply reference either `Result.lose` or the literal string `lose`.

```
import enum
import timeit
class Result(enum.Enum):
    lose = -1
    draw = 0
    win = 1

>>> timeit.timeit('Result.lose', 'from __main__ import Result')
1.705788521998329
>>> timeit.timeit('"lose"', 'from __main__ import Result')
0.024598151998361573
```

This is much slower than simply referencing a global variable.

```
k = 12

>>> timeit.timeit('k', 'from __main__ import k')
0.02403248500195332
```

My questions are:

- I know that global lookups are much slower than local lookups in Python. But why are enum lookups even worse?
- How can enums be used effectively without sacrificing performance? Enum lookup turned out to be completely dominating the runtime of my tic-tac-toe program. We could save local copies of the enum in every function, or wrap everything in a class, but both of those seem awkward.

Comment: I think it's probably the attribute retrieval that is slow. If you do something like `lose = Result.lose` and then test against `lose`, whether its local or global, I think you'll see a measurable speedup.

Comment: Thanks, that works pretty well. Do you know why attribute lookup is so much slower than even global lookup? I know that locals are stored in a fixed-length array while globals are in a dict, but what's the deal with attributes?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. And I couldn't tell you anything with certainty without reading CPython source. If I had to guess, I would say that objects are implemented with associative arrays or maps or whatever under the hood (only a possibility, not to be taken as fact), so there may be a cost to the hashing algorithm used on attribute names which are like string keys to a hash table, but this is all speculation. In any case, you now know how to minimize it in the case of repetitive lookups. Localization ftw.

Comment: The fact that enum attribute lookup is very slow is actually a performance bug: https://bugs.python.org/issue23486 , In Python 3.5 this is sped up by quite a bit (3x slower instead of 20x slower)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are timing the timing loop. A string literal on its own is *ignored entirely*:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def f(): "lose"
... 
>>> dis.dis(f)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

That's a function that does nothing *at all*. So the timing loop takes `0.024598151998361573` seconds to run 1 million times.

In this case, the string actually became the docstring of the `f` function:

```
>>> f.__doc__
'lose'
```

but CPython generally will omit string literals in code if not assigned or otherwise part of an expression:

```
>>> def f():
...     1 + 1
...     "win"
... 
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              3 POP_TOP             

  3           4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

Here the `1 + 1` as folded into a constant (`2`), and the string literal is once again gone.

As such, you cannot compare this to looking up an attribute on an `enum` object. Yes, looking up an attribute takes cycles. But so does looking up another variable. If you really are worried about performance, you can always *cache* the attribute lookup:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> import enum
>>> class Result(enum.Enum):
...     lose = -1
...     draw = 0
...     win = 1
... 
>>> timeit.timeit('outcome = Result.lose', 'from __main__ import Result')
1.2259576459764503
>>> timeit.timeit('outcome = lose', 'from __main__ import Result; lose = Result.lose')
0.024848614004440606
```

In `timeit` tests all variables are locals, so both `Result` and `lose` are local lookups.

`enum` attribute lookups do take a little more time than 'regular' attribute lookups:

```
>>> class Foo: bar = 'baz'
... 
>>> timeit.timeit('outcome = Foo.bar', 'from __main__ import Foo')
0.04182224802207202
```

That's because the `enum` metaclass includes a [specialised `__getattr__` hook](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c16d3f5af23f/Lib/enum.py#l241) that is called each time you look up an attribute; attributes of an `enum` class are looked up in a specialised dictionary rather than the class `__dict__`. Both executing that hook method and the additional attribute lookup (to access the map) take additional time:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('outcome = Result._member_map_["lose"]', 'from __main__ import Result')
0.25198313599685207
>>> timeit.timeit('outcome = map["lose"]', 'from __main__ import Result; map = Result._member_map_')
0.14024519600206986
```

In a game of Tic-Tac-Toe you don't generally worry about what comes down to insignificant timing differences. Not when the *human player* is orders of magnitude slower than your computer. That human player is not going to notice the difference between 1.2 microseconds or 0.024 microseconds.

Comment: Ah, okay, so the loop dominates when not using the enum. But what accounts for the difference between referencing the global variable `k` and referencing `Result.lose`?

Comment: @EliRose: the lookup does have a cost, yes. So where that actually matters (e.g. in a time critical part of your code, in a loop), cache the lookup in a local.

Comment: I'm more interested in the internals than I am in my tic-tac-toe game, in which there are many ways to solve this problem. Why is attribute lookup so much slower than global lookup?

Comment: @EliRose: the name lookups are *local*, not global. Looking up the attribute on the enum is 2 lookups; the `Result` lookup, then the `lose` attribute lookup. `enum` hooks into the latter; there is a specialised [`__getattr__` hook](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c16d3f5af23f/Lib/enum.py#l241) that is executed to handle the attribute lookup, so that takes a little more time still.